# How to fix 'child connection forced to terminate due to client_idle_limit:180 is reached'

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am working on a Python script which sends queries to a PostgreSQL database. It works just fine until it stops for 3 minutes for unknown reasons. I can't seem to identify why it stops, probably due to internet connection. After it continues the following exception is thrown:

> unable to read data DETAIL:  child connection forced to terminate due
> to client_idle_limit:180 is reached server closed the connection
> unexpectedly  This probably means the server terminated abnormally
> before or while processing the request. Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "/scraper/Database.py", line 36, in fetch_one_iin
> cursor.execute(query) psycopg2.OperationalError: unable to read data DETAIL:  child connection forced to terminate due to
> client_idle_limit:180 is reached server closed the connection
> unexpectedly  This probably means the server terminated abnormally
> before or while processing the request.

How can I avoid this exception?

I use psycopg2==2.9.3, Python 3.8.

I thought about sending 'SELECT 1;' query from time to time, but it seems like a silly workaround.

I tried adding the following code to every function connecting to database:

```
        if self.conn.closed != 0:
            self.logger.warning("Connection is closed. Reconnecting...")
            self.conn = psycopg2.connect(self.connections[0])
```

But it didn't work, exception was still there.

Comment: You left out the part that the connections are going through  `pgpool` which is where the [client_idle_limit](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/runtime-config-connection-pooling.html) is coming from. You have two choices: 1) Increase the limit. 2) Better yet close the connections more often so you don't trip the limit. That is part of the purpose of a pooler,  open and close connections  with less overhead and so do it more often.

Comment: Do you mean [pgpool] (https://pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page)? And by the way do you think it is a better idea to create connections for every query and closing them after or to have one connection for all queries?

Comment: Yes that `pgpool`. Connections are overhead so the fewer you have open at a time and the shorter you have them open is better. So it is a balancing act. It makes sense to combine related queries in one connection as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out conn.closed only returns non-zero value if the connection had been closed from the client side, that's why my program wasn't reopening the connection as intended.

Following the advice from @Adrian_Klaver I tried doing this:
I removed this code:

```
  if self.conn.closed != 0:
        self.logger.warning("Connection is closed. Reconnecting...")
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(self.connections[0])
```

And had a separate connection for every single query, i.e. I opened a connection at the start of a method and closed it at the end. Now the problem is fixed.